# Strange behavior of coffee compiler

Tags: node.js, coffeescript

I found an strange behavior of **coffee** compiler on an simple expression, which differs from a interactive compiler reaction at coffeescript.org site.

When I try to compile next string with coffee:

**`(console.log i; break) for i in [0..10]`**

I got:

> **SyntaxError: In repl, cannot use a pure statement in an expression.at SyntaxError (unknown source) ...**

But the same expression in interactive compiler at coffescript.org compiled just fine, as expected by me to:

```
var i, _i;

for (i = _i = 0; _i <= 10; i = ++_i) {
  console.log(i);
  break;
}
```

Why coffee don't like () grouping here?

**UPD**

Another strange thing - it happens not always, sometimes, after a lot of tries and variations, coffee starts to compile absolutely the same expression normally, without errors.

But seems like in interactive mode, coffee fails always.

Another strange thing I found - this error happens only when I use the 'break' keyword. Expression '(console.log i; i+1) for i in [0..5]' works just fine and returns an array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the REPL tries to give you the result of every expression (and save it as `_`). So internally, it's compiling

```
_ = ((console.log i; break) for i in [0..10])
```

which breaks the compiler because you can't use `break` in a list comprehension.

I would recommend creating `myfile.coffee` in your favorite editor and running it (`coffee myfile.coffee`) rather than using the REPL.

Comment: Thank you for detailed description! 
But there is one thing - I meet this error during an *.coffee script compilation, and it happens not always the same expression sometimes compiled normaly, sometimes not.

And first time I meet it, I spend a lot of time searching in my code where it happens, because message has no line number.